# Could I make an AD-HOC network on my mobile?

Tags: android, adhoc

Is it possible make an AD-HOC network on my mobile? How can I do it?

Could I make an AD-HOC on Android Mobiles?

Comment: This should go to android.stackexchange.com. But you can download Wireless Tether if you have a rooted phone.

Comment: Also, try not to shout. Your headline looks like you are talking about AN AD-HOC NETWORK OF DOOM!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You would need at a minimum a wireless base station. I don't believe any phones do this. You may be able to do it through bluetooth though.

Comment: The Wireless Tether app can do it with a rooted phone.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Android does not support ad-hoc wireless networks (other than Bluetooth):
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Nokia, you can use the software JoikuSpot to create a Wifi hotspot that is ad hoc. It is free with port 80 and a cheap full version supports all ports. I have used it a lot. Very easy to use.

An Android phone cannot connect to an ad hoc network (it can with a hack, you can google for).
So my Android can not connect to my Nokia with JoikuSpot.

There are also several softwares that can make an ad hoc wifi hotspot on Android. Search in Android marketplace. Yes, it sounds funny. An Android phone can create an ad hoc hotspot, but cannot connect to it.